# Can't open Microsoft Teams with python (3.8) script using any method

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, microsoft-teams

I am trying to make a script to automate the login into Microsoft Teams and all of my code works except the part where the application has to be opened. The weird thing is that this is capable of opening any other application except MS Teams (Chrome, Notepad, Firefox, Edge etc.)

Here's the relevant code:

```
def openfile():
    if os.stat("stor.txt").st_size == 0:
        name = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        newfile = open("stor.txt", "w")
        newfile.write(name)

    else:
        name = (open("stor.txt", "r").read())
        os.startfile(name)
        sleep(5)
        keyboard.write(open("user.txt", "r").read())
        keyboard.press("enter")
        sleep(3)
        keyboard.write(open("pass.txt", "r").read())
        keyboard.press("enter")
```

I tried this with `os.startfile`, `os.system(start..)` and every other method on the web. Doesn't work.

The value I'm passing in to `os.startfile()` when I try to run Teams is `C:/Users/Raghav/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams/Update.exe`.

Comment: Side note: storing your password in an unencrypted file on your hard drive probably isn't the best option. Doesn't Teams leave you logged in after the first time automatically?

Comment: What value does `name` have when you run `os.startfile(name)`?

Comment: @Chris the string value is- C:/Users/Raghav/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams/Update.exe

Comment: as I said, somehow, this script can open everything except teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

os.system("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe")
```

For applications that have an address like above, there are also some tips:

1. Sometimes **Discord.exe** name of the file in the address have **"Discord.exe"** (with double-quotes). **Remove it**.
2. Instead of single `\` use double `\\` in the address.

It will definitely work GO AHEAD ✔

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I don't recommend storing your password in plain text like that. It's not very secure, and if another program takes focus at the right time your code will even type your password somewhere else!

Teams should remember your credentials after the first time you log in. I suggest letting it handle that part.

In any case, running [`os.startfile("foo.exe")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) is like double-clicking on `foo.exe`. The file name that you're passing in is `C:/Users/Raghav/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams/Update.exe`, and `Update.exe` doesn't look like something that should launch Teams to me.

Inspecting the Teams shortcut in my own Start menu, I see that things are a bit more complicated. This shortcut runs `Update.exe` *and passes it some arguments*:

```
C:\...\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"
```

There is no way to pass arguments to a program with `os.startfile()`. Try [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) instead:

```
os.system('C:/Users/Raghav/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams/Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"')
```

There are [lots of other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/354577) to run external commands in Python, but this is likely simplest since you don't need Teams' output streams. This command *should* return `0` if it succeeds and some other value if it fails.

Comment: Is there any way to get over the problem that arises if my username is two words, i.e there's a break in the statement? for example if the path is - C:/Users/Raghav Sinha/AppData

Comment: Try putting quotes around the path to the executable: `os.system('"C:/Users/Raghav Sinha/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams/Update.exe" --processStart "Teams.exe"')`

Comment: still getting it: ```'C:/Users/Raghav' is not recognized as an internal or external command,```
operable program or batch file.

Comment: though I cant test it, I'll assume that it works. let me try and figure out a way around this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RaghavSinha, you're using exactly the command I put in my comment? With quotes starting before `C:/` and ending after `Update.exe`?

Comment: yes. maybe it ignores any repeating quotes inside existing single quotes?

Comment: I don't have a space in my username, but I can successfully run commands with spaces in the path using `os.system()`, e.g. `os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"')`. I'm only using a raw string because of the backslashes—if you're using forward slashes you shouldn't need that.